# compare coordinate/directional objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a grid and get a direction to move. This direction can be

```
  Vector2Int movementDirection = new Vector2Int(/* this can be
     (0,1) // up
     (0,-1) // down
     (-1,0) // left
     (1,0) // right
  */);
```

**Vector2Int is a class from the Unity Framework!**
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2Int.html

When moving from bottom to top I want to check all the cells around my targetCell. But I don't want to check the bottom cell because this cell is where I come from.

When I move from the left to the right, I don't want to check the left cell.

So I went for this

```
private void CheckCells(Vector2Int movementDirection)
    {
        Vector2Int[] cellDirections = { Vector2Int.up, Vector2Int.down, Vector2Int.left, Vector2Int.right };
        cellDirections.Where(direction => !direction.Equals(movementDirection)).ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < cellDirections.Length; i++)
        {
            // check the other 3 cells
        }
    }
```

This array will still have a length of **4**. It seems I can not compare a `Vector2Int.up` with `(0,1)`

I tried

`!direction.Equals(movementDirection)`

and

`directon != movementDirection`

How can I start a loop for just 3 of 4 directions? The given parameter should remove the fourth direction from the array.

Maybe I don't need an array?

Comment: you might want to try replacing `equals` with `==` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Equals.html

Comment: Usually, comparing floating point numbers is done with an epsilon. (if the difference is smaller than epsilon, we act like they are equal). this is because they are imprecise. your movement direction might be off by a millionth, causing `equals` to indicate they are different.

Comment: I updated my post, I use `Vector2Int` now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line :

```
cellDirections.Where(direction => !direction.Equals(movementDirection)).ToArray();
```

does nothing to your `cellDirections` variable, as you don't assign the result.

Either try :

```
cellDirections = cellDirections
                 .Where(direction => !direction.Equals(movementDirection)).ToArray();
```

or any other assignment :

```
var anyVar = cellDirections
             .Where(direction => !direction.Equals(movementDirection)).ToArray();
```

Note that you could also just loop through your `cellDirections` and add an `if` inside your `for` :

```
foreach (var direction in cellDirections)
{
    if(!direction.Equals(movementDirection))
    {
        // check the cells
    }
}
```

Comment: or, even cleaner : `foreach(var direction in cellDirections.Where(direction => !direction.Equals(movementDirection)) { /* check direction variable */ }`

Comment: @TimothyGroote I don't know which is cleaner of using `Where` inside the `foreach` or adding an `if` but you've got a point here